# Finding specific values in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a scenario whereby the `accountNo` is not a `Primary Key` and it has duplicates and I would like to search for accounts that have `priority` with the value of `'0'`. The `priority` field is a `varchar` data type. The following table is an example:

```
ID AccountNo Priority
1    20         0
2    22         0
3    30         0
4    20         1
5    25         0
6    22         0
```

I want to get duplicates or single records of `accounts` that have `priority` of value `'0'` with the condition that other duplicates of the same `accountNo` doesn't have any `priority` value `'1'`. For example, `accountNo 20` have 2 records but one with `priority` valued `'1'` so it shouldn't be in the output. For `accountNo 22`, although it has 2 records but both have `priority` of value `'0'`, therefore it is considered as one of the result.

```
AccountNo
  22
  30
  25
```

The problem i encountered here is that I can only find accounts with `priority` `'0'` but those accounts is prone to the possibility of having duplicate `accountNo` with `priority` valued `'1'`. The following code is what i have implemented:

```
SELECT AccountNo
FROM CustTable
WHERE PRIORITY = '0'
GROUP BY AccountNo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Priority` field takes only values in `('0', '1')`, then try this:

```
SELECT AccountNo
FROM CustTable
GROUP BY AccountNo
HAVING MAX(Priority) = '0'
```

otherwise you can use:

```
SELECT AccountNo
FROM CustTable
GROUP BY AccountNo
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Priority <> '0' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a AccountNo if it has priority 0, but only if there exists no other row with same AccountNo that has priority 1.

```
SELECT DISTINCT AccountNo
FROM CustTable t1
WHERE PRIORITY = '0'
and not exists (select * FROM CustTable t2
                where t1.AccountNo = t2.AccountNo
                  and t2.PRIORITY = '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work regardless of the RDBMS you use, as not all of them accept a 'group by' without selecting an aggregate function (e.g. max()).
It'd be better if you mention the RDBMS you use, going forward.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tmp.AccountNo
FROM 
    (SELECT AccountNo, MAX(Priority)
    FROM CustTable
    GROUP BY AccountNo
    HAVING MAX(Priority) = '0'
    ) tmp
```